# For which $\alpha$ the function series $f_{n}(x)=n^\alpha xe^{-nx}$ has uniform convergence to $f(x)=0$ in $[0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

$$
f_n(x)=\frac{n^\alpha x}{e^{nx}}
$$
I'm struggling with the idea of uniform convergence, so i'm not sure this solution is correct.

The function is defined between $[0,1]$, positive and continuous.
Also $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0$ for every $x\in[0,1]$.

I check for the maximum of the function:
$$
(\frac{n^\alpha x}{e^{nx}})'= \frac{n^\alpha e^{nx}-ne^{nx}n^\alpha x}{(e^{nx})^2}=0
$$
$$
n^\alpha e^{nx}=ne^{nx}n^\alpha x \iff nx=1 \iff x=\frac{1}{n}
$$
And when we put $\frac{1}{n}$ in the original function:
$$
\frac{n^\alpha \frac{1}{n}}{e}=\frac{n^{\alpha-1} }{e}
$$
And when $n\to\infty$ the maximum goes to infinity for every $\alpha > 1$ so there is no uniform convergence.

When $\alpha = 1$ The maximum of the function is $\frac{1}{e}$ for every n and so $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\not<\epsilon$ for $\epsilon < \frac{1}{e} \implies$ no uniform convergence.

When $0<\alpha<1$ the maximum of the function is $\frac{\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}}{e}$ and when $n\to\infty$ it equals $0$ so $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for **every $x$** $\implies$ there's uniform convergence for $0 < \alpha < 1$

When $\alpha=0$ the maximum of the function is simply $f_n(x)=\frac{n^0-1}{e}=0$ and thus there's uniform convergence (because if the max is zero than that's true for every other x because this function is positive).

When $\alpha<0$ the maximum of the function is $\frac{n^{\alpha - 1}}{e}=\frac{\frac{1}{n^{-\alpha + 1}}}{e}$.

The $n$ is to the power of a positive number so when $n\to\infty$ the maximum approaches zero $\implies$ there's uniform convergence when $\alpha<0$

So to summarize: the function series has uniform convergence when $\alpha<1$.